# Is this the correct Google Analytics tracking code for multiple subdomains and main domains?

Tags: google-analytics

This is a two part question:
1) Is my new Google Analytics tracking code correct?
2) With the new code, I noticed a HUGE drop in reported sessions. Is this because the tracking code is more accurate or because my tracking code is wrong.

My Domains (example):

```
www.domain.org
abc.domain.org
cde.domain.org
www.domain.info
abc.domain.info
cde.domain.info
```

My OLD Google Analytics Tracking Code:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-99999999-9', 'domain.org');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

My NEW Google Analytics Tracking Code:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-99999999-1', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', [/^domain\.(org|info)$/]);
</script>
```

Note: I see my second script doesn't have "ga('send', 'pageview');" could that be the reason for the HUGE drop in reported sessions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your second question, a huge YES! If you don't have a pageview, then you don't have a way to indicate the start of a session.

Your setup looks correct - just might want to check to see if the auto-link domains accepts regex as I have a feeling it doesn't, ie.:

```
ga('linker:autoLink', [domain.org, domain.info]);
```

You might have to list them all out.

Don't forget to add your different domains to the referral exclusion list.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Just after I posted this question, I went in and added the "send pageview" code.

Comment: Also, I got the regex code for autoLink from the official Google Analytics page: 

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain?hl=en

Comment: I will double check the referral exclusion list soon, but wanted to make sure this was corrected now. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

New code is better.
You have drop in number of sessions because now your sessions count in a right way.

Now if user jump from domain.org to domain.info it will be 1 session.
With old code it will be 2 sessions.